# jQuery toggle two clicks required in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

This works fine on all other browsers but in firefox, I need to click my 'show more reviews' link twice for my on click event to fire. any ideas?

```
$moreReviewsWrapper.toggle(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var moreReviewEndpoint = $(this).data().more;
        if(moreReviewEndpoint) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
                url: moreReviewEndpoint,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $moreReviewsLink.text('Loading more reviews ...');
                },
                success: success,
                error: function(){
                    $moreReviewsLink.prop('hidden', false);
                    $moreReviewsLink.text(originalText);
                    $commonError.show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}, function() { $(this).off(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your jQuery looks kind of weird to me.  [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is a show/hide function, and the first argument is a duration argument.  You're passing it a function that creates an event handler.  My guess is jQuery ends up running that function to evaluate it for a number (to use as the duration), which *then* sets your event handler.

I'm not sure what `toggle()` is supposed to be doing here, but moving your event listener outside of `toggle()` will fix your issue.